# Convert application to regular folder in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7

In IIS7, If I want to create an application, I just right-click on a folder to do it:
[image]

If later on I want to convert it back to a regular folder (not an application), how can I do it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Right click on application folder and select remove. The application will be converted as regular folder.

Comment: It's 2021, and we from the future thank you for your service :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an automated approach, but you should be able to get most of the way there by moving all of the code for your site (except code behind) into an App_Code folder at the top level, and by removing the DLL for your site from the bin folder.

You may also need a few other tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the app and then select remove.

Comment: Actually, doing so will delete the application *and* content. Proceed with caution. http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/brad/use-the-iis7-remote-administration-tool-to-mark-a-folder-as-an-application/

Answer (score 0):

I have made the Following changes.

> In IIS Right-click the same Virtual application and select "remove"
>   option. This will convert the application to the folder only.